# Wireless shuts down after RDP on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, remote-desktop

I have two Laptops with windows 7 installed.  They are both on the same wireless network.  There is no wired connection.  Machine A is able to ping Machine B.  I then initiate a RDP connection from A to B and receive a logon prompt.  I enter my credentials and then it looks as though the desktop is being readied... but the desktop never shows up and then the session hangs until I am prompted with an error stating that "The Connection to the Remote Computer was Lost"

At this time Machine A is no longer able to ping B.  So I log into machine B the old fashioned way and can briefly see that the wireless connection was in a failed state, and then it comes back up and I am able to ping B from A once again.

However, as soon as I try to RDP to B, this process is repeated.

In the System EventLog I see

> Event ID: 56
>
> Source: TermDD
>
> Message: "The Terminal Server security layer detected an error in the protocal stream and has disconnected the client."

Anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: I bet you have problems copying files between the machines over the wireless network too?  what kind of wireless AP/router are you using? and what about the machines connecting to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if there are problems with the network.  Those problems could be duplex mismatching or bad NIC drivers.

Just to troubleshoot, if you use a crossover cable and just link them together do you get the same error?  If not, you'd cut out RDP/authentication causing the issue and can then move to the network.